# Problem with video after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype, radeon, vlc

I upgrade my computer from 13.10 to 14.04. It is a 32 bits system with a Radeon HD6400 series. After upgrading skype crash when video is connected and VLC also crash when I try to play a video. On the other side, Cheese is working perfectly and I have XBMC installed which also develops well. I have done a clean installation and it happens the same things. I follow some recommendations, like the installation of the video libraries.
Anybody has a clue?? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Open up Software & Updates and navigate to the "additional drivers" tab. Select the proprietary Radeon driver from the list of drivers.